# How to stop an android repeating alarm from a notification action

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

I'am trying to find a way to use an NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction(...) to call some code to stop a repeating alarm without starting an activity... but as i understood so far the only thing I can do with this is start intents with Activities.
There's any way I can stop the alarm without leaving the notification?

Comment: I think you are trying to perform an action in the wrong place. Notification, as its name implies, is not a place to perform your business logic. That is why it gives you the option to invoke an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add request to alarm manager by calling set() function with PendingIntent as parameter. You just need to call cancel() with same PendingIntent, in order to stop it; though I note very clear about your notification question.

Comment: Thx but I know how to cancel an alarm. My problem is to call the code from an notification button without leaving the notification.